# From popup.html, how can I run a javascript function by button onclick?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build an extension for Chrome, but I'm a newbie and I'm having trouble understanding the Docs provided by Google. I want the extension to have a popup that shows a few buttons, and when a button is clicked, I want to run a script.

This is my setup:

popup.html

`<button id="test1" onclick="getSite();">button 1</button>`
`<button id="test2" onclick="getSite();">button 2</button>`

content_script.js

`function getSite(){alert('getSite works!');}`

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the chrome javascript api, as I see others saying use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, but I can't figure out where that line goes. Can anyone help me? I'll give you a cookie! or just an upvote.. or maybe both?

Comment: Both answers below are correct.  You cannot use inline event attributes, and you cannot reference variables in your content script from your browser action popup.  Use `addEventListener` in a separate JS file, and use message passing via your background page.

Comment: Ohhh.. I think I just figured it out, but I'll test more before confirming. This is how you use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`
Instead of just typing out `alert('test');` you write

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
{code:"alert('test')"});
window.close();`

Comment: That is correct; you can also use `{file:"some_file.js"}` to inject a whole file.  Each tab has an isolated execution evironment for extension scripts, and those are all separate from the background paage.  `executeScript` is how the background page gets a particular tab to run code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having this problem because of restrictions imposed by the [Google Content Security Policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html). It mentions that iniline javascript like the one that you have mentioned in you code will not be executed.  Try removing the `onclick="getSite()"` from your HTML markup to `content_script.js`. Use `addEventListener` function to attach the event to the button.

Comment: I did it this way, and it seems to working, somewhat. The alert shows, but it fades away right away. I'm guessing I'll have to try it by passing the message to the background page.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned on which page you want your scripts to run `onclick`, in Popup.html page  or the page on which user is currently working on the browser. If it is just the `popup.html page` in which you want to execute your script, include them in `popup.html` page itself.

If however you want to execute them on the user's browser page, You will have to pass a message to your background page, which in turn will execute `chrome.tabs.executeScript` with current tab's id and `{file: 'yourjsfile.js'}` as arguments.

Comment: Trying this in popup.html:

`<script>
function getSiteThree()
{
alert('test3');
}
   

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {     document.getElementById('button3').addEventListener('click', getSiteThree);
});
</script>`

in body:
`<button id="button3">button3</button>`

It's not running the function. But when I reference the same script in content_script.js, the pop up shows, albeit briefly. I'm sure I"m doing something wrong, so I'll keep trying this a little more, but if you see something obvious, please do let me know!

Comment: I've never used the event `DOMContentLoaded`. Can you try `window.onload` instead and check if it works for you?

Comment: Jophin Joseph has mentioned correctly with the link that you cannot use inline javascript in your `popup.html`. You will have to put all your js in a file and load it through `<script>` tag.